# Several Errors in a System.g.cs file

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm just trying to code a Library Management System with **C#**, first, it works perfectly and the program started without any error, then I started to code a new function for my SQL Data Access, after doing that I got that Errors:
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Bm8N.png)
After removing the code I've written before the program doesn't work at all. I've installed the packages **Dapper** and **SQLite**.
Thank you, Lenni.

Comment: if you named you class "System", chose smth else to avoid collision with primary .net namespace

Comment: You have errors in *.g.cs files, which are auto-generated by your IDE. Try to clean your solution and rebuild the project. That should get rid of - maybe obsolete - *.g.cs files.

Comment: Thank you for your comments :D .  I don't have any class called System, so I think that's not the problem, but thank you :). @Bin4ry I also tried your advice but the Errors are still there.